# Simple tetrad exercises

Tags: general-relativity

I am reading [Andrew Hamilton's really nice notes](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/astr5770_14/grbook.pdf) on [Tetrad formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism) of general relativity, and I am having trouble finding assignments/exercises on tetrad formalism. Would anyone know a good resource with exercises aimed at getting some intuition with tetrads (preferably with solutions)?

I would prefer not go to spin tetrads or get involved with quantum physics.

Edit after FenderLesPaul's helpful comment:
I would prefer to have exercises which relate the tetrad frame to the metric somehow e.g. starting with $g_{\mu \nu} e^\mu_{\ a} e^\nu_{\ b}=\eta_{ab}$ (e is the vierbein, $\eta$ is of Minkowski form)

Comment: Do you have access to MTW?

Comment: I now do, I borrowed it from the library.

Comment: @FenderLesPaul I noticed there are some exercises on tetrads but it's not exactly what I would like. There were tetrads where they had pre-defined the tetrad basis. Do you know of a good sourrce that starts from e.g. defining the tetrad frame via metric $g_{\mu \nu}e^\mu_a e^\nu_a=\eta_{ab}$ and go from there?